# Can I generate opeanpi yaml in Cloud Run?

Tags: swagger, fastapi, openapi, google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

Using `FastAPI` locally I can generate an openapi yaml file using /docs.
Now I am running the API in `API Gateway/Cloud Run`, is there any way I can generate the yaml file from code running in `Cloud Run`?

Comment: Couldn't you request the same URL from your cloud run instance?

Comment: Did you test it? Do you have an error?

Comment: I get a method not allowed mesage.